# wordpress fresh install showing blank page

Tags: wordpress

I am using linux. I downloaded wordpress zip file. I have a folder life.com and unzipped the wordpress contents in it.

I have created a virtual host life.com (its not a live site). its only accessible from my computer.

I set my apache web server and hosts so that `life.com` points to the folder.

When i open life.com it shows blank page.  I just renames index.php to index1.php then it shows the contents of the folder life.com

I put a sample.php with hello. when i open life.com/sample.php it shows hello

there is no problem with the apache and php.

generally the fresh install of the wordpress should show the page

```
    There doesn't seem to be a wp-config.php file. I need this before we can get started.

    Need more help? We got it.

    You can create a wp-config.php file through a web interface, but this doesn't work for all server setups. The safest way is to manually create the file.

    Create a Configuration File
```

instead of opening life.com, i made a folder in the apache root directory /srv/wordpress and unzipped the files there.

when i open localhost/wordpress then it shows

```
        There doesn't seem to be a wp-config.php file. I need this before we can get started.

    Need more help? We got it.

    You can create a wp-config.php file through a web interface, but this doesn't work for all server setups. The safest way is to manually create the file.

    Create a Configuration File
```

its showing blank page when i open from virtual host (life.com) but opens correctly from localhost/wordpress.

Comment: you cant just unzip the WP files, you have to go through a short install process [Installing Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

Comment: Please understand the question. I freshly installed wordpress and when i open life.com it should show the text in the brown box. Also i made a database and put the wp-config.php with all the required fields. still it shows a blank page. I see in error.log but no errors. I even put wp_debug as true, still balnk page. Its able to connect to the database, its able to run php but a blank page

Comment: @celeriko, I think he knows that - he mentioned the general flow of the installation in his question.

Comment: it wasn't clear that he performed the install process, all he said was he unzipped the WP folder which is not sufficient in itself.  On another note, `life.com` is registered to Time Magazine not you, not sure if you were using it as an example or if that really is the domain name you're trying to use..

Comment: sorry life.com is a virtual host i have created for testing. Its on my local computer i am testing. so i gave a random name. I wanted to test a theme so gave a life.com. Please see the updated post

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. Just to correct what @SanthoshYedidi said, you are only unzipped but not yet installed. I also get the same problem like santhosh said. I have a VPS MyWebsite.com running on ubuntu, and i've put the unzipped wordpress folder on /var/www it shown blank page without any wordpress installation but when i put on /var/www/<somefoldername> then accessing Mywebsite.com/somefoldername the wordpress intallation guide is appearing.

Comment: I guess the installation dependency is broken, wordpress usually showing a blank page some of its part are broken. Lets together find the answer for this problem @SanthoshYedidi

Comment: i was having this issue, and went to site.com/readme.html hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Going to the folder in which Wordpress was installed just resulted in a blank page.

Visiting the `readme.html` page worked, however, and it directed me to `wp-admin/install.php` which could then run the install process.